# Retrieve both payload and headers of a Kafka message that could not be deserialized

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using spring-kafka 2.1.7 to consume JSON messages and I want to handle messages that cannot be deserialized correctly.
To override the default behavior, which loops over the same message, I extended the JsonDeserializer to override the deserialize method.

```
public class CustomKafkaJsonDeserializer<T> extends JsonDeserializer<T> {

    public CustomKafkaJsonDeserializer(Class<T> targetType) {
        super(targetType);
        this.objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        try {
            return super.deserialize(topic, data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Problem deserializing data " + new String(data) + " on topic " + topic, e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my consumer and its configuration  :

```
@Service
public class Consumer {

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.out}", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory", errorHandler = "customKafkaListenerErrorHandler")
    public void consume(@Payload Lines lines, @Headers MessageHeaders messageHeaders) {
        //treatment
    }

}

@Configuration
public class ConsumerConfig {

    ...

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Lines> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(), new CustomKafkaJsonDeserializer<>(Lines.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Lines>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Lines> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", this.bootstrapServers);
        props.put("group.id", this.appName);
        props.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put("value.deserializer", CustomKafkaJsonDeserializer.class);
        props.put("security.protocol", this.securityProtocol);
        props.put("sasl.mechanism", this.saslMechanism);
        props.put("sasl.jaas.config", this.saslJaasConfig);
        return props;
    }
}
```

Finally, I implemented my own error handler in order to send erroneous data to an other topic.

```
@Component
public class CustomKafkaListenerErrorHandler implements KafkaListenerErrorHandler {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaErrorService kafkaErrorService;

    @Override
    public Object handleError(Message<?> message, ListenerExecutionFailedException exception) throws Exception {
        log.error("error handler for message: {} [{}], exception: {}", message.getPayload(), message.getHeaders(), exception.getMessage());
        kafkaErrorService.sendErrorToKafka(message.getPayload().toString(), exception.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }

}
```

This is what happens when I consume a faulty message :

- the CustomKafkaJsonDeserializer tries to deserialize the message and catches an exception.
- the payload can be retrieved in the catch block, but not the headers. null is returned to advance the offset.
- it gets to the handleError method of the error handler. message.getHeaders() returns the correct headers but message.getPayload() returns a KafkaNull object. Hence, I am not able to send both the payload and the headers at this step.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning null, return a rich object containing the data and headers.

Comment: In 2.2, we have a new ErrorHandlingDeserializer but that, doesn't handle the headers; we'll fix it in 2.2.1: github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/845 – Gary Russell 11 mins ago

Comment: Indeed, I have a KafkaNull because null is returned. I implemented the suggested solution, but couldn't find a clean way to do it.
Funny thing is that with a producer that has a JsonSerializer as value serializer (instead of StringSerializer), I correctly retrieve the payload and headers in the error handler.